# Does meteor framework 1.8 support latest version of angular like 8 or 7?

Tags: angular, meteor

I am about to start a javascript project and planning to use meteor framework. Whilst playing around the basic App from meteor site, I noticed they use a angular version 1.7.8. I was wondering if its possible to use more higher version of angular like 6/7/8 ? Is this possible or its not supported ? Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [meteor-rxjs](https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-rxjs)

You use the angular-cli to structure your application, and you use this package to access your data.

It hasn't been touched for two years, so I don't know if it is still maintained. You might want to look at [angular-fire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire). The Meteor people have moved on to graphql.

The original Meteor framework won't work with the latest angular.